# Vectorization for computing variance of a vector split at different points

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a 1-D array `arr` and I need to compute the variance of all possible contiguous subvectors that begin at position 0. It may be easier to understand with a for loop:

```
np.random.seed(1)
arr = np.random.normal(size=100)

res = []   
for i in range(1, arr.size+1):
    subvector = arr[:i]
    var = np.var(subvector)
    res.append(var)
```

Is there any way to compute `res` witouth the for loop?

Comment: So you just want *expanding variance?

Comment: @ddejohn rather expanding

Comment: Correct, thanks Moz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since `var = sum_squares / N - mean**2`, and `mean = sum /N`, you can do `cumsum` to get the accumulate sums:

```
cumsum = np.cumsum(arr)
cummean = cumsum/(np.arange(len(arr)) + 1)
sq = np.cumsum(arr**2)

# correct the dof here
cumvar = sq/(np.arange(len(arr))+1) - cummean**2

np.allclose(res, cumvar)
# True
```

Comment: What is variable `s`, do you mean `cumsum`?

Comment: @Brenlla Yes, careless refactor on my part.

Answer (score 3):

With pandas, you could use `expanding`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(arr).expanding().var(ddof=0).values
```

NB. one of the advantages is that you can benefit from the `var` parameters (by default `ddof=1`), and of course, you can run many other methods.